# QGIS 2.4.0 doesn't support multiple types of geometry in GML file

Tags: qgis, polygon, geometry, gml, inspire

I'm testing GML 3.2.1 data according to INSPIRE Data specification (version 3.0). Data for theme Cadastral Parcels shall have both polygon geometry and definition point. When I download data from my WFS service to QGIS 2.4.0, it renders automatically as points. I'm used to it. In older versions of GIS, all I had to do was overwrite geometryType attribute from 1 to 3 in automatically generated .gfs file. Yes, it's a bit complicated, but it worked.

In QGIS 2.4.0 it doesn't work. After rewriting .gfs file, I got no geometry at all. If I want to get polygons, I have to download GML data and erase all referencePoint elements. So my question is: does anybody have any idea how to visualize GML data with both point and polygon geometry as a polygon in QGIS?

This question may rather be asked to QGIS developers, but at first I'm trying existing solutions.

Answer (score 1):

For visualizing complex feature GML in QGIS you'll need to wait for QGIS 3.0 (or 2.99 if you can't wait) and the [QGIS GML Application Schema Toolbox plugin](https://github.com/BRGM/gml_application_schema_toolbox).